# How to import a 2D float matrix from .txt file into a 2D float array in Java?

Tags: java, java-io

My data.txt file takes the following format:

```
14 -0.0 0.29964766 10.7192135 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
15 -0.0 0.29964766 10.7192135 0.0 0.0 0.0 -8.4375 -36.6875 2.25
15 -0.0 0.29964766 10.7192135 0.20300001 -0.083000004 -0.019000001 -8.4375 -36.6875 2.25
16 -0.0 0.29964766 10.7192135 0.20300001 -0.083000004 -0.019000001 -8.4375 -36.6875 2.25
16 -0.0 0.29964766 10.7192135 0.136 -0.072000004 -0.020000001 -8.4375 -36.6875 2.25
16 -0.0 0.29964766 10.7192135 0.136 -0.072000004 -0.020000001 -8.4375 -36.6875 2.25
17 -0.0 0.29964766 10.7192135 0.136 -0.072000004 -0.020000001 -8.4375 -36.6875 2.25
20 0.21792556 0.40861043 9.956474 0.136 -0.072000004 -0.020000001 -8.4375 -36.6875 2.25
21 0.21792556 0.40861043 9.956474 0.136 -0.072000004 -0.020000001 -8.4375 -36.375 1.375
...
```

It always has 16 columns. But the **row number is unknown** because it is actually the number of data set collected, and thus depend on how long are the data being collected.

I wish to import these data into a 2D float array in Java so that I can easily take out one column for analysis purpose.

Can someone kindly help?

---

The unknown row number is not an issue. I can easily write out a `getRowNumber()` function.

What really bothers me is how to really import all the numbers in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the number of the line in a file you can read it and put a counter in the while loop

```
    public int lineCounter(){
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
     int i =0;   
     try {
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                i++;
            }
            String everything = sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Then you can set up your 2d matrix and work it as you want

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks! But what really bothers me is how to build the 2D array... This part is easy to me though..

Comment: For instance, take the line that start with: 14 -0.0 0.29964766 10.7192135 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 how do you want to split it up?

Comment: String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.lenght; i++) { float f = Float.parseFloat(tokens[i]); }